# clustering markers on android maps v2

Tags: android, maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

Recently I worked on an android project in which I managed to add markers to a MapView and cluster those markers if they were too close to each other. Now I have to do the same using the new MapFragment - Google Maps Android API v2.

The markers now are succesfully added to the map, but I can't manage to make the clustering part and I can't find any usuable description about this topic.
Do you know a way to implement this using the new API?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/).

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the comment, I've already found this link, but unfortunately only after implementing my own solution. Anyway, I'll try this one as well, maybe its performance is better when working with 500+ markers, it's pretty slow on my Samsung Galaxy S :(

Answer (score 12):

For anyone still in need of a clustering solution, also take a look at [Clusterkraf](https://github.com/twotoasters/clusterkraf/). It's an Apache v2 licensed open source clustering library for the Google Maps Android API v2. It clusters points based on pixel proximity, animates transitions between clusters when zooming, handles thousands of markers, and supports Android v2.2 and higher.

Comment: This answer should be a comment. It is really nothing more than a link.

Comment: Nice library! The sample project is here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twotoasters.clusterkraf.sample&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS50d290b2FzdGVycy5jbHVzdGVya3JhZi5zYW1wbGUiXQ.. Works well on the Hero so it's gotta be solid.

Comment: @MinceMan Link not working.

Comment: Looks like they took the sample down